# How to capture all keyboard input to a custom element?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Here is my problem: I've got a swf loaed inside my loader an in that swf I have a keylistener:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, this.__onKeyDown, false, int.MAX_VALUE);
```

Now I'm adding a TextInput to this stage and I would like this input to catch all keyboard events while I'm focusing it. Is it possible to do so that native __onKeyDown will not fire until my TextInput has lost focus?

Thank you for your answers and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give your listener higher priority (which you are), and stopAllPropogation in your handler.  I've never tried this with an embedded swf so if it doesn't work right away, you could also try listening to the event in the capture phase (third parameter in addEventListener).

```
function __onKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    //rest of you handler code here 
}
```